# maximising L^2 norm of linear combination of vectors

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, functions, optimization

Let $f$, $g$ and $\lambda$, $\mu$ be complex-valued functions defined on the real line. Provided $|\lambda|\leq 1$ and $|\mu|\leq 1$, is there a way to bound the quantity
$$
\|\lambda f-\mu g\|_{L^2}=\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\lambda f-\mu g|^2dx\right)^{1/2},
$$
assuming $f,g$ are in ${L^2}$? It feels like it should be possible to bound it by $\|f- g\|_{L^2}$ using standard techniques (Lagrange multipliers maybe?) but I haven't had any success so far. If someone could help me or point me in the right direction I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: I guess $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are constants.

Comment: $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are also complex-valued but $|\lambda|\leq 1$ and $|\mu|\leq 1$

Comment: Are they complex constants or functions?

Comment: complex-valued functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $|\lambda f-\mu g|\le |f|+|g|.$ Thus $$\|\lambda f-\mu g\|\le \|\,|f|+|g|\,\|\quad (*)$$  Take $$\lambda (x)=\begin{cases}\overline{f(x)}/|f(x)| & f(x)\neq 0\\ 1 & f(x)= 0
\end{cases}$$ and $$\mu (x)=\begin{cases}-\overline{g(x)}/|g(x)| & g(x)\neq 0\\ -1 & g(x)= 0
\end{cases}$$ Then $|\lambda f-\mu g|=|f|+|g|$ and  we get equality in $(*).$

Comment: I see, thank you. So all can be said is that $\|\lambda f-\mu g\|_{L^2} \leq\||f|+|g|\|_{L^2}$, right?

Comment: That's right. For constant $\lambda$ and $\mu$ the answer is different $$(\|f\|^2+\|g\|^2 +2|\langle f,g\rangle|)^{1/2}$$